# Getting some metadata from cloud storage to cloud function

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, web3js

I want to grab a json file from my cloud storage to use in cloud function (this is in the '/post-account' route). Although, I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly, as the error logs are printing that web3 cant instantiate a contract without its abi (json interface).

I just need some hardcoded metadata for the cloud function. I have tried deploying with the json file local to the function dir, and requiring in the index.js, this did not work.

I could try copying the entire json interface into index.js as var, but this is thousands of lines of metadata.

**index.js**

```
'use strict';
const Web3 = require('web3');
const Contract = require('web3-eth-contract');
const axios = require('axios')
const fs = require('fs');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')();
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();


//options for cors midddleware
const options = {
  allowedHeaders: [
    'Authorization',
    'Origin',
    'X-Requested-With',
    'Content-Type',
    'Accept',
    'X-Access-Token',
  ],
  credentials: true,
  methods: 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  origin: 'https://test-cf-97bfc.web.app',
  preflightContinue: false,
};

// set headers for app.
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

  // Website you wish to allow to connect
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://test-cf-97bfc.web.app');

  // Request methods you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

  // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
  // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  next();
});


// Express middleware that validates Firebase ID Tokens passed in the Authorization HTTP header.
// The Firebase ID token needs to be passed as a Bearer token in the Authorization HTTP header like this:
// `Authorization: Bearer <Firebase ID Token>`.
// when decoded successfully, the ID Token content will be added as `req.user`.
const validateFirebaseIdToken = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Check if request is authorized with Firebase ID token');

  if ((!req.headers.authorization || !req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')) &&
    !(req.cookies && req.cookies.__session)) {
    console.error('No Firebase ID token was passed as a Bearer token in the Authorization header.',
      'Make sure you authorize your request by providing the following HTTP header:',
      'Authorization: Bearer <Firebase ID Token>',
      'or by passing a "__session" cookie.');
    res.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
    return;
  }

  let idToken;
  if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
    console.log('Found "Authorization" header');
    // Read the ID Token from the Authorization header.
    idToken = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];
  } else if (req.cookies) {
    console.log('Found "__session" cookie');
    // Read the ID Token from cookie.
    idToken = req.cookies.__session;
  } else {
    // No cookie
    res.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
    return;
  }

  try {
    const decodedIdToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken);
    console.log('ID Token correctly decoded', decodedIdToken);
    req.user = decodedIdToken;
    next();
    return;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error while verifying Firebase ID token:', error);
    res.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
    return;
  }
};




app.use(cors(options))
app.use(cookieParser);
app.use(validateFirebaseIdToken);

app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
  // @ts-ignore
  res.send(`Hello ${req.user.email}`);
});



app.post('/post-account', async (req, res) => {
  const { account, price } = req.body;
  console.log('account' + account);
  console.log('price' + price);
  //changing to matic node
  const web3 = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/09cbbdd922284d95a70c627ddf29012d');
  const address = "0xE981aFEeA8E3dB77003C1D56e7c1D42e470Ea775";

//fetch json from cloud storage. Incorrect?
  const abi = axios.get('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-cf-97bfc.appspot.com/o/abis%2Fabi.json?alt=media&token=26bb0e2f-872c-4ee9-ac0f-525b9d84af39')

  console.log('after artifact call');
  Contract.setProvider(web3);
  //error here.
  const contract = new Contract(abi, address);

  await contract.methods.totalSupply().call( function(error, result){
    if  (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(400).end;
    }
    else if (result) {
      res.status(200).json({ txResolved: "NFT awarded post", account: account, currentSupply: result  })
    }
});






});




exports.testAPI = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Do you have access to both the bucket and the json file? Is there a specific reason you are trying to use axios for it?
Could using the [official npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage) for bucket access be your solution? [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#code-samples) can help you access metadata for your json. Here is the code for installing the npm:
`npm install --save @google-cloud/storage`

Comment: I need a json file local to my cloud functions. Then, the node application can instantiate a contract instance for me to work with (call methods on smart contract)

Answer (score 1):

Before you can fetch any file from Cloud storage check the IAM policies and test if you can access it. If the Cloud Function   exists inside the same project as the Cloud Storage file there should be no problem with auth unless you modified these rules to be more strict. If you need to finetune the network access for the function you can check out these links  [for VPC networks](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/connecting-vpc) and  [for general networks](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings)

In a Cloud Functions you can use the npm [@google-cloud/storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage) to get a file from a cloud storage. You can get a file like show in documentation [link](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#get)

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const myBucket = storage.bucket('my-bucket');

const file = myBucket.file('my-file');

file.get(function(err, file, apiResponse) {
  // file.metadata` has been populated.
});

//-
// If the callback is omitted, we'll return a Promise.
//-
file.get().then(function(data) {
  const file = data[0];
  const apiResponse = data[1];
  // Code to use json file
});
```

Just remember to include the dependency in your `package.json`

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^5.8.1"
  }
```